# Boostrap 4 - Scrollspy issue

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm trying to rebuild my website from scratch. And I want to add a scrollspy to the top of my navbar.

I've already tried to add the `data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="100"`to my body tag, and define it in jQuery by using `jQuery('body').scrollspy();`.

But it's just not working. I looked into DevTools on Chrome, but I can't find any issues in it.

**My Navbar**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img height="45px" src="https://dellusion.app/assets/img/logo/textlogo.png" alt="Dellusion Records"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor" aria-controls="navbarColor" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/#top" data-easing="easeOutQuint">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/#latest" data-easing="easeOutQuint">Releases</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/#news" data-easing="easeOutQuint">News</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/#artists" data-easing="easeOutQuint">Artists</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/#contact" data-easing="easeOutQuint">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://open.spotify.com/user/dellusion_records"><i class="fab fa-lg fa-spotify"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://twitter.com/DellusionRec"><i class="fab fa-lg fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/DellusionRecords"><i class="fab fa-lg fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.youtube.com/DellusionRecordsOfficial"><i class="fab fa-lg fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.soundcloud.com/dellusion-records"><i class="fab fa-lg fa-soundcloud"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My question is how to get this scrollspy working? Because it's a pain in the head for this to be working.

A full example can be found [here](https://dellusion.app/)

Comment: why did you use navbar to show social media tags ?

Comment: It just feels better at the top than on the bottom. It should be instantly clear what their social media channels are. But I can place them at the bottom if it's in the way of the scrollspy function.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned the places I added in the comment lines.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>STACKOVERFLOW</title>
</head>


<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="0">
  <!-- Added Here  -->


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img height="45px" src="https://dellusion.app/assets/img/logo/textlogo.png" alt="Dellusion Records"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor" aria-controls="navbarColor" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#top" data-easing="easeOutQuint">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#latest" data-easing="easeOutQuint">Releases</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#news" data-easing="easeOutQuint">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#artists" data-easing="easeOutQuint">Artists</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact" data-easing="easeOutQuint">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://open.spotify.com/user/dellusion_records"><i
              class="fab fa-lg fa-spotify"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://twitter.com/DellusionRec"><i class="fab fa-lg fa-twitter"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/DellusionRecords"><i
              class="fab fa-lg fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.youtube.com/DellusionRecordsOfficial"><i
              class="fab fa-lg fa-youtube"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.soundcloud.com/dellusion-records"><i
              class="fab fa-lg fa-soundcloud"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Created Them for Example -->
  <div id="top" style="height: 700px; margin-top: 71px;" class="bg-warning">Home</div>
  <div id="latest" style="height: 700px;" class="bg-danger">Releases</div>
  <div id="news" style="height: 700px;" class="bg-primary">News</div>
  <div id="artists" style="height: 700px;" class="bg-info">Artists</div>
  <div id="contact" style="height: 700px;" class="bg-dark text-white">Contact</div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. It fully works in the demo. I copy/pasted your snippet into my project. However, on the production server, it just doesn't want to work. It seems like it doesn't want to add the "active" class to the "nav-link" class... It's really strange...

Comment: you are sure that you have written the tags that are required for bootstrap to work with javascript, right ? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#js  I'm talking about sticking the 3 tags here at the end of the body tags